# How to find out the PBS version installed in a cluster?

Tags: pbs

Whenever I submit a job array, I get one job ID in this form: `463880-1.hostname` with 463880 being the job ID and 1 the array ID, one job for each "array position".

Today I'm using a different machine, and it looks like a different PBS version, because an job array, size 10, resumes to this single job: `3310[].hostname`.

I like to know list both versions, to check if I need to change something in my scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `pbs-config --version` does that.

Answer (score 5):

qstat --version
such as:
pbs_version = PBSPro_12.3.0.xxx